# How can we get Json web token via angular?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have a rest service in Spring boot application.

I have a method, that accepts username and password as json data and checks this data, if they're true then service return JWT token.

[image]

When I call this method via angular, I can't get Authorization token and request send twice.

[image]

Why request send twice and how can I get token in angular?

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Payment} from './Payment';
import {HttpClient, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Home';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.http.post('http://localhost:8084/login', JSON.stringify({ username: 'mehman', password: 'mehman' }), { observe: 'response' })
      .subscribe((response: HttpResponse<any>) => { console.log(response); });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post service and component code. So we can understand your problem in better way and provide solution.

Comment: Probably a CORS issue

Comment: I add @CrossOrigin to my rest method for this issue => Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Yeah but that's why the request is sent twice. Once for OPTIONS, once for POST. And I think headers in the response are lazy loaded, so you need to access them to see them displayed

Comment: How can I prevent twice request?
I can't understand your second approach.

Comment: I added token to body of response in token generation source  as the below code.
res.getWriter().append("{\"token\":\""+TOKEN_PREFIX + " " + JWT+"\"}");
How can I prevent twice request sending?

Answer (score 0):

refer below solution you can refer & compare with your code for solution https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/

https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs